# Tme interval postgresql 2

Tags: postgresql, time, window-functions, intervals

I have a table which contains id (unique), number of system (system_id), timestamp time_change and status. When status 1 it means, system unavailable, when 0 - available:

```
CREATE temp TABLE temp_data_test (
       id int8 NULL,
       system_id int8 NULL,
       time_change timestamptz NULL,
       status int4 NULL
);



INSERT INTO temp_data_test (id, system_id, time_change, status) VALUES
       (53,1,'2022-04-02 13:57:07.000',1),
       (54,1,'2022-04-02 14:10:26.000',0),
       (55,1,'2022-04-02 14:28:45.000',1),
       (56,1,'2022-04-02 14:32:19.000',0),
       (57,1,'2022-04-05 03:20:18.000',1),
       (58,3,'2022-04-05 03:21:18.000',1),
       (59,2,'2022-04-05 03:21:22.000',1),
       (60,2,'2022-04-06 02:27:15.000',0),
       (61,3,'2022-04-06 02:27:15.000',0),
       (62,1,'2022-04-06 02:28:17.000',0);
```

And a table `date_dict` with date (just one column `date_of_day date`).

As you can see, status doesn't change everyday. But I need a statistics for each calendar day for each system.
So for day, that are not in the table I need add 2 rows for each system. First with timestamp 'date 00:00:00' and status opposite to first nearest status with a higher date (may be not in that day, but tomorrow).

And second with timestamp 'date 23:59:59' with opposite to nearest lower date (today, yesterday etc).

For this table I need something like

```
id    system_id       time_change          status
63       1        '2022-04-02 00:00:00'       0
64       1        '2022-04-02 23:59:59'       1
65       1        '2022-04-03 00:00:00'       0
66       1        '2022-04-03 23:59:59'       1-- cause system was available from 2 april
67       1        '2022-04-04 00:00:00'       0
68       1        '2022-04-04 23:59:59'       1
69       1        '2022-04-05 00:00:00'       0
70       1        '2022-04-05 23:59:59'       0--cause become unavailable in 2022-04-05 03:20:18
```

And so on for another system

I suppose, it can be divide into 2 parts with first row and second (00:00:00 and 23:59:59). My attempts lead to null in dates and I try to group by date, which didn't work as I can see.

Comment: why is id 65 status 0?

Comment: Because 2022-04-02 14:32:19 for system 1 status was change to 0 - available, and change again 2022-04-05 03:20:18 to 1 (unavailable). It means system worked all day  2022-04-03, that why I need mark that it become available in the 00:00:00 and unavailable at 23:59:59. In other side, 0 is opposite to 1, and 1 is the status of 2022-04-05 03:20:18 - nearest status of bigger date.